# How to run PowerPoint off OneDrive in browser in loop?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, onedrive, office365, presentations

I created a PowerPoint slideshow.  I want it to run it on a TV screen that has a built-in web browser, auto-loop, and I also want users to be able to view it from their laptops.  I currently can do this using google docs / google drive, but I'm trying to do this using mainly Office 365 technologies, and avoid google docs.

I want the following:

- website link to view a PowerPoint presentation.
- store the PowerPoint in OneDrive (for Business)
- automatically view each slide for 10 seconds (currently doing this successfully via the "transitions" settings)
- automatically loop to the beginning when reached the end (I configured this in "slide show setup" but it doesn't seem to work when presented online)
- full screen (hide any toolbars, bottom bars, etc.)
- I don't want it converted to a movie (I want it to act like a presentation when users are viewing it on their laptops).

Currently, I can manually load it up, and get it full screen, and the only show stopper is that it doesn't loop.  Preferably, the link would force it full screen without manually clicking to run the slideshow.

Google has nice URL parameters to tweak how the PowerPoint is presented.  It is unclear what Microsoft's URL parameters are and maybe my solution lies within understanding these...

Microsoft URL parameters that I see that I don't have complete understanding of:

- action: edit, view, embedview - documented at https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery.html#wopi-actions
- wdAr: ? (I'm guessing this means "aspect ratio")
- wdEaa: 1 or 0; 1 means "use default autoadvance settings from the file"
- wdModeSwitchTime: ?
- wdSlideId: ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to [turn the presentation into a video](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-your-presentation-into-a-video-c140551f-cb37-4818-b5d4-3e30815c3e83)? If the TV browser supports HTML5, you may use the [<video> loop Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_loop.asp), or make it loop manually in the browser.

Comment: I think that loading a video makes more sense than loading PowerPoint and dynamically displaying each slide over and over again. Much more efficient and can be displayed anywhere.

Comment: Since you are supposed to pass wd* query string values untouched, unlikely you really need them. You can set FULLSCREEN = true to get fullscreen. See https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery.html#term-fullscreen Dont see looping built in, consider using javascript timer and refresh.

Comment: Turning it into a video makes some sense for the TV, but not so much for viewing on an intranet webpage.  I guess it could be setup as a video for the tv and as a powerpoint for the webpage.  It works great in Google Slides though.  It would be nice if Microsoft would include the same feature as Google Slides.

Comment: The question was for the TV and I answered accordingly. Other and better solutions do exist for other devices,

Comment: Actually, the question was for looping a PowerPoint presentation without converting it to a movie, and the intention of the question was looping the actual powerpoint presentation and not a converted copy of it.  Regardless, your information is useful, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Thought I might share my finding, as I tried to achieve something similar:

[According to Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_winother-mso_2010/problem-with-continuously-looping-an-embedded/c6f65cfa-185f-4b0b-8617-787291eb2344), "the feature is not available in PowerPoint web app to play slideshow in loop."

Comment: Sadly this is true.  I was hoping someone had a clever simple solution to this.  (I probably should have awarded you the points for directly answering the question, but I was busy and it auto awarded.  And anyways, the other answer had some good alternatives.)

Answer (score 3):

Running PowerPoint on a TV is problematic.

If the TV is running Android and can install applications,
you may use the
[Microsoft PowerPoint app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.powerpoint).

If the TV browser supports HTML5, there are various utilities that
might help, such as :

- [Zamzar PPT to HTML5](https://www.zamzar.com/convert/ppt-to-html5/)
- [Converting Microsoft PowerPoint presentations to HTML5](https://elearning.adobe.com/2017/08/converting-microsoft-powerpoint-presentations-to-html5-web-pages/)
  using Adobe Captivate.

However, as TV browsers are usually quite limited, I believe there is
a much simpler solution, as follows :

- [Turn the presentation into a video](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-your-presentation-into-a-video-c140551f-cb37-4818-b5d4-3e30815c3e83) of a format that is supported by your TV
- You may display the video by the TV if it supports looping.
- If looping is not supported and you are obliged to use the TV browser, there are two options:

  1. Create an HTML5 page embedding the video and using the
      [loop Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_loop.asp)
  2. Otherwise, you may manually right-click the embedded video in the
     browser and choose Loop, or program it using JavaScript.

A video solution is basically run-anywhere and any-device.

Answer (score 0):

i found a hacky work around.  This will work if you know the timing of your powerpoint.

```
    <script>
        window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 20000);

function reloadIFrame() {
    document.getElementById('slideFrame').src = document.getElementById('slideFrame').src;
}
    </script>
```

so if you put an id="slideFrame" on the iframe of your embedded powerpoint and the wdEaa=1 as mentioned in the original question in the URL, your slide show will auto play to the settings on the slides... the iframe will then reload after 20,000 milliseconds  (so in my example, it took 20 seconds for my slideshow to complete. )   its not ideal but it works for a kiosk type show where you are looping a slideshow over and over on a web page.

Comment: not sure - but there may be a limit on the number of times sharepoint will load this file, it seems to get to a point where the show isn't showing any more - just a powerpoint logo.